# what's the difference and relation between local R data frame and SparkR data frame and RDD

Tags: r, apache-spark, machine-learning

I am new to Spark and now I am playing with SparkR running some ML algorithm. I often get confused about the local R data frame and SparkR data frame. what's the difference between local R data frame and SparkR data frame? What's the relation between them? And what's relation between them and RDD?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

RDDs behave differently to dataframes. RDDs exist in a pipeline, where each one is an iteration of the previous one, each time you apply a function to it. Each iteration is not stored separately in memory and just exists as an iteration of the last, where the RDD just knows the function that made it arrive at where it is. Loosely speaking, you must take a functional approach with lambda functions etc. and operations like for loops do not work on RDDs. By storing the data this way it makes Spark much quicker than more old-fashioned map-reduce packages.

SparkR dataframes also will have a different variety of functions available to it compared to local frames. I am assuming (as this is the case for pyspark dataframes and local pandas dataframes), the functions you use to append new columns and save the new dataframe to disk differ. For instance, with pyspark dataframes you use a withColumn() function to add a column instead of more traditional python. So, generally speaking, certain functions you would classically use on a local frame won't work on SparkR frames, as SparkR frames are mostly restricted to spark libraries.